# How to change collection images in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-8

My Design Code like this:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="42" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="302" Margin="12,471,0,0" Background="{StaticResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Change Color" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="137" FontSize="18" Foreground="Black" />
                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="33" Margin="163,3,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="41" Source="Assets/c1-1.png" x:Name="c1" Tapped="c1_Tapped" />
                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="212,4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="45" Source="Assets/c3-1.png" x:Name="c2" Tapped="c2_Tapped" RenderTransformOrigin="0.825,0.5" />
                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="33" Margin="262,3,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" Source="Assets/c2-1.png" x:Name="c3" Tapped="c3_Tapped" />

            </Grid>
```

Code Behind code like this:

```
private void c1_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Images = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            Images.Add(@"Assets/02_perspective_img_1.png");
            Images.Add(@"Assets/02_perspective_img_2.png");
            Images.Add(@"Assets/02_perspective_img_3.png");

            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        private void c2_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Images = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            Images.Add(@"Assets/03_perspective_img_1.png");
            Images.Add(@"Assets/03_perspective_img_2.png");
            Images.Add(@"Assets/03_perspective_img_3.png");

            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        private void c3_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Images = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            Images.Add(@"Assets/01_perspective_img_1.png");
            Images.Add(@"Assets/01_perspective_img_2.png");
            Images.Add(@"Assets/01_perspective_img_3.png");

            this.DataContext = this;
        }
```

When tapped on particular image need to show that particular images.But not showing that .
only showing first clicked items images only.Please let me know how to change the collection. 
i am binding that collection to flipview control in windows 8.

```
        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left"   Source="{Binding}" Height="450" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="792" x:Name="imagecontrol" Stretch="Fill"/>

            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>



    </FlipView>
```

Comment: do you want that when you click on a any image then your images property got updated with the collection you specified in particular tapped event..am i right..

Answer (score 0):

I'm going under a few assumptions. One is that the FlipView control has it's ItemsSource binding to your Images property. If you are going to set the DataContext to yourself (the page in question) you need to do one of a few options.

One: Do not set Images to a new collection. You are using an ObservableCollection so take advantage of it. Clear the collection and add items back to it.

```
private void c3_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Images.Clear();
    Images.Add(@"Assets/01_perspective_img_1.png");
    Images.Add(@"Assets/01_perspective_img_2.png");
    Images.Add(@"Assets/01_perspective_img_3.png");
}
```

Two: Implement INotifyPropertyChanged in the page and fire the PropertyChanged event when you reset the Images property

```
private ICollection<string> _images;
public ICollection<string> Images 
{
    get { return _images; }
    set 
    {
        _images = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Images");
    }
}
```

You will probably find that you will need more and more bindings. Because of this it is usually best to have a separate ViewModel class that holds your data.

Comment: in case of Windows-8 project's Page that inherit Layoutaware page..the Inotifypropertychange interface can not be inherited ..i think that is the problem..just check your ans..and update it ..

Answer (score 0):

the way Shawn is suggested is i will recommend but when i tested it in case of **Windows 8 app page** which is inherited by **LayoutAwarePage** then in that case - Firstly you got error that Page Can not Implement **InotifypropertyChanged** secondly when i Tested it With **ObsevableCollection** that time also it is not working..so i have come with this workaround for solving your problem. in this case you just have to update the **itemsSource** Property of your **FlipView** Control each time when you are updating your Image collection..

```
private void c1_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Images = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Images.Add(@"Assets/02_perspective_img_1.png");
        Images.Add(@"Assets/02_perspective_img_2.png");
        Images.Add(@"Assets/02_perspective_img_3.png");

       FlipviewControlName.ItemsSource = Images;
    }
```

I know this is not the proper solution but i think i will solve your problem...